# Proving a space is a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Given a topological space defined as $A=A_1 \cup A_2$ with

$A_1=\{(x,y) \in R^2 \space \space|\space \space x^2+y^2=1, x<0\}$,

$A_2=\{(x,y) \in R^2 \space \space|\space \space |x|+|y|=1, x\geq0\}$.

Show that $A$ is a one-dimensional manifold.

So if we omit all the tiny details (e.g. showing $A$ is Hausdorff, connected etc.) and just get to the point of finding a differentiable structure on $A$, we need to find a collection of charts $(U_i, \phi_i)$ s.t. $A=\cup_iA_i$ and that the transition functions $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}$ are $C^{\infty}$.

So if I start by defining the subsets

$U_1=\{(x,y) \in A : y>0\}$

$U_2=\{(x,y) \in A : y<0\}$

$U_3=\{(x,y) \in A : x>0\}$

$U_4=\{(x,y) \in A : x<0\}$

it's clear $A=\cup_iA_i$. But what about the maps? Let's say I take:

$\phi_1=x$

$\phi_2=x$

$\phi_3=y$

$\phi_4=y$

However, I've just thought of these off the top my head without any justification other than the fact the variable for $\phi_i$ is different from the restricted variable in the subset $U_i$. (I don't even know why I'm doing that!) There must be some small trick that tells me how to chose my maps once I've defined my subsets?

I'm quite sure $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}$ are $C^{\infty}$, but how can I show this? In words I could probably explain it, but writing something mathematically correct is a bit different. What about e.g.:

$\phi_1(x,y)=x \implies \phi_1^{-1}(x)=(x,y) \implies \phi_3 \circ \phi_1^{-1}=\phi_3 ( \phi_1^{-1}(x)) = \phi_3 (x,y)=y$?

Which is obviously $C^{\infty}$. But I'm not convinced I've done that right. Any help?

Comment: I don't think the space is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ because there should be a singularity at $(1, 0)$, although I'm not certain about this point. However, there is definitely a smooth structure on $A$ because it is homeomorphic to a circle and so you can just define the smooth structure to be that of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, taking your coordinate chart maps, let's compute the transition maps.

On $U_{1} \cap U_{3}$: For $t \in \phi_{3}(U_{1} \cap U_{3}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\phi_{1} \circ \phi_{3}^{-1}(t) = \phi_{1}(1 - t, t) = 1 - t$$
which is nice and $C^{\infty}$. Also, 
$$\phi_{3} \circ \phi_{1}^{-1}(t) = \phi_3(t, \sqrt{1 - t^{2}}) = \sqrt{1 - t^{2}}$$
which is not $C^{\infty}$ at $t = 1$ but that value is not in $\phi_{1}(U_{1} \cap U_{3}).$ So, these two transition maps are $C^{\infty}$ and the checks in the other charts are almost the same.

Edit: I made a pretty big mistake in the second computation (which would hold for $U_{2} \cap U_{3}$ not for the other direction of the map).

For $t \in \phi_{1}(U_{1} \cap U_{3})$, $\phi_{1}^{-1}$ maps into the first quadrant. Hence, we should have
$$\begin{align*}
\phi_{3} \circ \phi_{1}^{-1}(t) &= \phi_{3}(t, 1- t) \\
&\text{because $t$ must be the $x$ coordinate and }\\
&\text{$1- t$ is the $y$ coordinate for such points in the first quadrant}\\
&= 1 - t \end{align*}$$

This is still smooth. The computation I had previously done by mistake should have been done for $U_{1} \cap U_{4}.$

Comment: Can you define $t$ in your answer please?

Comment: So, $\phi_{1}^{-1}$ is a map from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow A$ and hence, $t$ is some arbitrary real number. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Could you also tell me if there is a specific way to choose my maps for each subset? As I said in the question, I was just making these maps up because it seems like they work. Is there not some sort of trick I can use to choose maps for each subset? e.g. would $\phi_1=y$, $\phi_2=y$, $\phi_3=x$, $\phi_4=x$ still work?

Comment: The charts you chose are the natural choices: projection maps onto the $y$ and $x$ axes, on connected domains where these projections are one to one. It is a theorem that the charts of a submanifold of $\mathbb R^N$ can always be defined in a similar manner. It's confusing me that it seems to work here, though, because, as Christian Blatter points out, $A$ is certainly not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I think it works here because all of the kinks are not in the intersection of any two charts.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yes I'm slightly confused because we have two conflicting answers to this question! Although I can't see a problem with Siddharth's solution here. When you say my charts are the natural choices, was I just lucky in choosing these maps? Why can't we just set all $\phi_i=x$, for example??

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh How do i Know when to use $1-t$ and $\sqrt{1-t^2}$. This is the absolute root of my problem.

Comment: @user13223423 So, the maps you choose have to be bijective, which is why you can't just set al the maps to $x$. For the second question, I just computed the transition maps. I didn't know that those maps would be the ones that came out so I'm not sure I understand the problem. Could you explain exactly what is troubling you?

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Ok thanks for the help. So there's two questions which once I understand then I'm fine with this problem. 1. (I think this is basic maths) How do you find $\phi^{-1}_1(t)=(t,\sqrt{1-t^2})$ and $\phi_3^{-1}(t)=(1-t,t)$? 2. When choosing my maps for $U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is there any "trick" that I should look for to choose appropriate maps? There must be something about each subset which makes you think "Ok well this map would be the most suitable for this subset".

Comment: So for your first question, it really was just direct computation. Basically, the $x$ component of $\phi^{-1}(t)$ had to be $t$ and the $y$ component was given by the circle constraint. For your second question, when you have to actually construct the charts, intuition such as the one you relied on for this problem can be useful. I don't know of general tricks but sometimes the charts are well known. Often, you don't actually compute coordinate charts but use general theory such as "regular fibres of smooth functions from a manifold $M$ to another manifold $N$ are submanifolds of $M$."

Comment: But why the circle constraint?? For $\phi_1^{-1}$, which is a map for $U_1$, $(y>0)$, this region involves both $x^2+y^2=1$ and $|x|+|y|=1$. So why have you chosen the circle constraint and not the other constraint? Sorry if I'm missing something here

Comment: Damn, I messed up. I should edit the answer. It's not $\sqrt{1 - t^{2}}$ but $1 - t$. It's because we are looking at $\phi_{1}^{-1}$ on $\phi_{1}(U_{1} \cap U_{3})$ which maps into the first quadrant.

Comment: I'm very sorry for adding to your confusion. I fixed the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Your space $A\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ via
$$f:\quad A\to S^1,\qquad {\bf z}\mapsto{{\bf z}\over |{\bf z}|}\ .$$
As $|{\bf z}|\geq{1\over\sqrt{2}}$ on $A$ this  $f$ is continuous, and furthermore it is obviously a bijection. It follows that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Now you could transport the differentiable structure on $S^1$ via $f\>$ to $A$, and then $A$ would become a smooth manifold. In addition the  $C^\infty$ structure on $A$ would be compatible with the topological structure $A$ has inherited from ${\mathbb R}^2$.

But your space $A$ is not a smooth submanifold of ${\mathbb R}^2$ because of the kinks at $(0,\pm1)$. There is no window $W:=[-h,h]\times[1-h,1+h]$ such that $A\cap W$ can be written as a graph $$y=\phi(x)\qquad(-h<x<h)$$
with $\phi\in C^\infty$.

Comment: You've shown me that we don't have a smooth manifold, however Siddharth's answer says we do have a smooth manifold and I can't see a problem with the solution presented.

Comment: Siddharth's  answer corresponds to my second paragraph. What I'm saying in the third paragraph is that this manifold structure on $A$ is not directly inherited from the embedding of $A$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$.